# store to hdfs as one file from two files

Tags: hive, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop .

Is it possible that I have two file with same structure, 
With the use of hive can I join that files and store it to hdfs as a one file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hive is intended for querying in Hadoop. If you want to combine two files, this can be achieved using Unix command as well, below is command,

server-domain$ cat file1 file2 >> COMB_FILE

And CREATE table on top of it.

Comment: but is it possible to join two file and insert into hdfs through hive?

Comment: Intention of hive id for querying data, still you can create external table on top of same structured files and other way if you are loading data in managed hive table you can use below solution, but this one is ideal for small file issue with when querying data in hive.

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading data into managed hive table below things should be enable to merge a reducer output if the size is less than an block size.

- hive.merge.mapfiles -- Merge small files at the end of a map-only job.
- hive.merge.mapredfiles -- Merge small files at the end of a map-reduce job.
- hive.merge.size.per.task -- Size of merged files at the end of the job.
- hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize -- When the average output file size of a job is less than this number, Hive will start an additional map-reduce job to merge the output files into bigger files. This is only done for map-only jobs if hive.merge.mapfiles is true, and for map-reduce jobs if hive.merge.mapredfiles is true.